# replace part of an int or string in a pandas dataframe column upon condition

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime, replace

I have a pandas dataframe with a column representing dates but saved in int format. For several dates I have a 13th and a 14th month. I would like to replace these 13th and 14th months by the 12th month. And then, eventually transform it into date_time format.

```
Original_date
20190101
20191301
20191401

New_date
20190101
20191201
20191201
```

I tried by replacing the format into string then replace only based on the index of the months in the string [4:6], but it didn't work out:

```
df.original_date.astype(str)
for string in df['original_date']:
    if string[4:6]=="13" or string[4:6]=="14":
        string.replace(string, string[:4]+ "12" + string[6:])
print(df['original_date'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.str.replace` with regex

```py
df['New_date'] = df['Original_date'].astype(str).str.replace('(\d{4})(13|14)(\d{2})', r'\g<1>12\3', regex=True)
```

```
print(df)

   Original_date  New_date
0       20190101  20190101
1       20191301  20191201
2       20191401  20191201
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a regular expression?

```
s = pd.Series('''20190101
20191301
20191401'''.split('\n')).astype(str)
s.str.replace('(?<=\d{4})(13|14)(?=01)', '12', regex=True)
```

Yielding:

```
0    20190101
1    20191201
2    20191201
dtype: object
```

(Nb you will need to reassign the output back to a column to persist it in memory.)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the replace and logic in a seperate function, which also gives you the option to adapt it easily if you also need to change the year or month. `apply` lets you use that function on each row of the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

def split_and_replace(x):
    year = x[0:4]
    month = x[4:6]
    day = x[6:8]
    if month in ('13', '14'):
        month = '12'
    else:
        pass
    
    return year + month + day
    

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'Original_date': ['20190101', '20191301', '20191401']    
    }
)

res = df.Original_date.apply(lambda x: split_and_replace(x))

print(res)
```